# Disable controllers in certain API version

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-core

We are developing a new API version in our application, so that we basically have a

```
namespace Bla.V1.Controllers
[ApiController]        
[ApiVersion("1")]
public partial class SampleController : ControllerBase {}
```

and a

```
namespace Bla.V2.Controllers
[ApiController]        
[ApiVersion("2")]
public partial class SampleController : ControllerBase {}
```

We've also configured API versioning (`AddApiVersioning`), so that when somebody tries to access e.g. `api/v3/sample/action`, he will get a version not supported error response, provided by the API versioning middleware.

Now the V2 version is in development and we want to make it available only for the development stage. The controllers code will be deployed to production, we want however to disable the V2 version for production.

We would do it with a feature flag, but what should be done to hide the V2 controllers?
I was thinking:

- Somehow do not register the V2 controllers. Didn't find a suitable option in AddControllers()
- Set maximum version to V1 in the API versioning middleware. This works only for headers, doesn't block access to V2 controllers

I'm currently thinking about writing an authorization attribute that would deny access based on the feature flag status and apply it to V2 controllers. Is there a better and more elegant way to do this?

Comment: If the `ApiVersioning` package doesn't do it by default (I've not looked), your approach would be my first thought too.  Could you create an attribute that inherits the `ApiVersionAttribute` and override the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case somebody is interested at some point. Our controller code is autogenerated from a Swagger definition. So I added the following code to the generation template, which gets invoked in each controller method:

```
if (!this.IsV2Enabled())
            {
                var protocol = this.Request.IsHttps ? "https" : "http";
                return this.BadRequest(new
                {
                    error = new {
                        code = "UnsupportedApiVersion",
                        message = $"The HTTP resource that matches the request URI '{protocol}://{this.Request.Host}{this.Request.Path}' does not support the API version '1'."
                    }
                });
            }
```